How to play a Signal at higher sampling rate without changing the frequency content of the signal?
I have a real-time data consisting of (multiplexed) frequencies 79MHz, 34MHz and 127MHz. The data is collected using an ADC of sampling rate 500MSPS. The signal has been captured for 2$\mu$s, hence has 1000 samples.
If I play this data through a DAC of the sampling rate 500MSPS, the frequencies of the signal remain undisturbed.
But, I want to play this data samples through a DAC at a sampling rate higher than 500MSPS say at 1024MSPS.
How can I play the data without changing the frequencies? Is there any simple technique to do so? Please help.

There is a number of methods in python libraries (like numpy, scipy) to do interpolation and resampling of data series. If you are a novice, start with a linear interpolation by numpy.interp(...), compute an error of interpolation on your data, leveraging your knowledge of source waveform (three sine waves). The error can be as great as ten percent, which is most often unacceptable. Test scipy.interpolate(...) with different splines and estimate the errors. You may need to compare spectra of the signals and their interpolated time series rather than absolute/relative errors of interpolated time series.
Then you can test resample methods, like scipy.signal.resample(...), scipy.signal.resample_poly(...). Beware of the implementation of these methods: a Fourier method is used for processing, so the signal is assumed to be periodic. If constituent waves of your signal (79MHz, 34MHz and 127MHz of your data) were on the order of an inverse period (1/2us of your waveform), the resampled signals may become noticeably different for a periodic waveform (your data repeating every 2 us) as compared to the single 2us burst case. Whether it is the case for you, depends on the required resampled data precision.
This code sample is written to help you start:
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

duration = 2E-6
fs = 500E6
N = duration * fs
t = numpy.linspace(0, float(duration), num=int(N), dtype=float)

f_resample = 1024E6
N_resample = duration * f_resample
t_interp = numpy.linspace(0, float(duration), num=int(N_resample), dtype=float)

s = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*79E6*t) + numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*34E6*t) + numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*127E6*t)

plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Signal/Interpolation')
plt.plot(t, s)

s_interp = numpy.interp(t_interp, t, s)

plt.plot(t_interp, s_interp)

plt.figure(2)
plt.title('Signal - Interpolation')
s1024 = numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*79E6*t_interp) + numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*34E6*t_interp) + numpy.sin(2*numpy.pi*127E6*t_interp)
plt.plot(t_interp, s1024-s_interp)

plt.show()

To master scipy methods, you have to learn from the scipy documentation and to experiment with function parameters.
